# Change class on the div wrapper of a form element

Tags: 6, forms

Is there a way to add or change a class to a form wrapper (the div's) using the form api?

Or is that just done with the theme function ?

If so which theme function is used to change that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a theme function. Which theme function to use is the question. :)

Comment: Ah you're right there.

Comment: I think you can also use the [#attribute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#attributes) key to define a class

Comment: @Mika A. This only applies to the <input> tag i'd like to change the class of the wrapper (a <div>).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override [`theme_form_element()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6) normally if you want to change the theming globally. If you're interested in modifying just one specific form element then I'm aware of a couple of choices.

1. You can register a new theme function for the particular type of form element you're interested in (eg. textfield). You then create this theme function (based on the original, eg. [`theme_textfield()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/6)) but that doesn't call `theme('form_element', ...)` at the end (you could either handle both the wrapper and the element in the one theme function, or you could make a separate wrapper theme function and use that). Finally you add a `#theme` property to a particular form element, and that element will get your custom theming.
2. You can create a template file called `form_element.tpl.php` which just has the default behaviour of `theme_form_element()` and then use `hook_preprocess_form_element()` to add a template suggestion. Then you create the new template that matches the suggestion. You often hear people mentioning that templates are slightly slower than functions, and for such a frequently used theme call I can imagine people balking at using a template. I've never done any measurements for this myself however. Also, you need to have enough context at the preprocess stage to be able to make the suggestion.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee Do you want to change the wrapper on all elements, or just one particular one?

Comment: just a single one.

Comment: @chrisjlee I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can use *wrapper_attributes* property.

```
$form['example'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Example'),
  '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => ['wrapper-class']],
];
```

Comment: This answer helped me, but note that it applies specifically to Drupal 8.x and later.

Comment: This is what i was looking for.. Thanks for it

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a super old thread, but I'v been learning how to alter form elements and add classes. I got around to making a custom module:

```
function yourtheme_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 case'webform_number_whatever':
   _yourtheme_form_add_wrapper($form['submitted']['yourfieldhere'], array('form-field-some-style', 'not-label', 'whatever-other-styles-you-want'));
 break;
}

function _yourtheme_form_add_wrapper(&$element, $classes = array(), $type = array('form-item', 'form-type-textfield'), $removeTitle = FALSE){
  $element['#prefix'] = '<div class="' . implode(" ", $classes) . '"><div class="' . implode(" ", $type) . '">';
  $element['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: This is a good alternative solution - don't add a class to the wrapping div, just wrapping the wrapping div in your own div and they you can apply whatever classes you want.

Answer (score 3):

To Change the "wrapper" you need to override form_element.
Basically all form elements get rendered with the form_element theme `theme_form_element($element,$value);` (form.inc file)

So to change how this renders your form elements you simply copy that function to your template.php folder and rename it to: `phptemplate_form_element($element,$value)`

now you can make any changes and they will be used instead of the original function

1. Copy `theme_form_element($element,$value);` from form.inc
2. Paste it into (your theme) template.php
3. rename it to: `phptemplate_form_element($element,$value)`
4. clear all theme cache
5. make whatever changes you want and they will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Importantly, theme_form_element will only modify the direct parent wrapper div and this may not be the intended target for CSS effects.

[Although not programmatic, if one simply wants to apply a class to a node field's top-wrapper (it's wrapper's, wrapper's, wrapper) one can I suppose use "Field group" module by selecting "Manage Fields" for a particular content type and select "Add new group" as a simple DIV. Then the label can be removed and desired classes assigned to the additional wrapper (but now we have even more wrappers) - with unlimited nesting]

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
'#prefix' => '<div class="new_class">', '#suffix' => '</div>'
```

and this will wrap it around

Answer (score 0):

Make wrapper attributes configurable!

Create your own form-element theme function in your theme...
`sites/all/themes/MY_THEME/theme/form-element.theme.inc`

```
function my_theme_form_element($variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];

  $attributes = isset($element['#my_theme_wrapper_attributes']) ?
    $element['#my_theme_wrapper_attributes'] : array();

  ...

  $output = '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . "\n";

  ...
}
```

Then you can do stuff like this...

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['mail']['#my_theme_wrapper_attributes']['class'][] = 'form-field--inline';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are come cases in which neither `#prefix/#suffix` nor `#attributes => array('class')` give the desired results.  My particular case is adding a class to the ajax-wrapper div around a managed_file element.  `#prefix/#suffix` creates a new container and `#attributes/'class'` modifies the class of an inner element, not the outermost.

The normal outermost div is just

```
<div id="edit-doc1--XX-ajax-wrapper">
```

which is difficult to target in CSS.  I can target `[id^="edit-doc"]` or `[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]` but both of these target more than just the elements I wanted.

The solution I came up with is to add a [`#process` element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#process) to the form and manually manipulate the element's code.  Here's the `#process` attribute added to the form item's declaration:

```
$form['doc1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#process' => array('mymodule_managed_file_process'),
);
```

And here's the `mymodule_managed_file_process()` function:

```
function mymodule_managed_file_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {

  // Call the original function to perform its processing.
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);

  // Add our own class for theming.
  $element['#prefix'] = str_replace(
    'id=',
    'class="managed-file-wrapper" id=',
    $element['#prefix']
  );

  return $element;
}
```

Relying on string substitution isn't very portable, so use `str_replace` at your own risk.  This code, however, does indeed alter the outermost DIV to add the necessary class:

```
<div class="managed-file-wrapper" id="edit-doc1--XX-ajax-wrapper">
```